# How to get the custom attributes of a method?

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, sos, clrmd

Assuming we have a method defined as below.

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    [My("beautifulName")]
    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
         // whatever.
    }
}

public MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public MyAttribute(string name) => Name = name;
}
```

Now we got a memory dump of this application, we can use ClrMD to find the `SomeClass` type easily, then we can easily find the `DoSomeThing` ClrMethod. Now, how can I find the corresponding `MyAttribute` instance and get the `beautifulName` value?

Comment: what memory tool are you using? you'll have to read the il metadata to know what attributes are applied

Comment: @DanielA.White: WinDbg, SOS or ClrMD as the tags say.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? All instances of that class have the same value, so any `SomeClass` object will have the value `"beautifulName"`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, because I don't have the code, only have the dump, so I need a way to detect the `beautifulName` in the dump itself.

Comment: Write the DLL to disk and open it in dotPeek / dnSpy?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to "write the dll to disk" from the memory dump. And I want to do this task automatically...